# Does a javascript look up table execute a function before or after initialization?

Tags: javascript, performance

My apologies if this has been asked before, but i couldn't find anything on it with any keywords i could think of.

I have an array in javascript and i want to determine its min/max value depending on the mode i'm in, so I have a function:

```
function arrayMinMax(array, mode) {
  // return min/max value from 1D array
  return {
    0: Math.min.apply(null, array),
    1: Math.max.apply(null, array)
  }[mode]
}
```

My question is: when this function is called, are both the values for min and max calculated or only the value of the min or max chosen with `mode`? If the former this would have bad performance compared to the latter.

Comment: both are calculated. The execustion goes as you see it, first an object is formed, then a specific object key element is returned

Comment: To get the latter, wrap them in functions: `return { 0: function() { return Math.min.apply(null, array); } , ... }[mode]()`

Comment: RJO's solution is good, though I don't think the object is necessary here at all. It just adds an extra layer to unwrap. May as well just check the mode, then call a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you can just toggle which function to call based on mode:

```
/* @param {number} mode - 0 for min, 1 (or any non-zero value) for max
** @returns {number} result of calling Math.min or Math.max on array (may be NaN)
*/
function getMinMax(arr, mode) {
  return mode? Math.max.apply(Math, arr) : Math.min.apply(Math, arr);
}
```

Or if you like less code:

```
function getMinMax(arr, mode) {
  return Math[mode? 'max' : 'min'] .apply(Math, arr);
}
```

Calling *Math* methods with *this* set to *Math* isn't explicitly required anywhere, it just seems sensible and is no more to type than *null*.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it's the one I ended up using

Answer (score 2):

Both values will be calculated. I would recommend you to use 'strategy' pattern here. So it will look like:

```
getArrayMinMax: function (array, strategy) {
    //you should pass Math.min or Math.max
    return strategy.apply(null, array)
};
```

so it may be used in that way:

```
getArrayMinMax([1, 2, 3, 4], Math.min);
```

Comment: Here is more detailed description for http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/strategy-design-pattern

Answer (score 1):

To get lazy evaluation, you can wrap them in functions:

```
function arrayMinMax(array, mode) {
  // return min/max value from 1D array
  return {
    0: function() { return Math.min.apply(null, array); },
    1: function() { return Math.max.apply(null, array); }
  }[mode]();
}
```